# How does WebSocket protocol enforce access control for non-browser clients?

Tags: websocket

According to [RFC 6455 websocket protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), `browser client` will include the HTTP `Origin` header field in the WebSocket handshake phase. And WebSocket server will use that `Origin` to check if the client has access.

But for a more capable `non-browser client`, the `Origin` header in the handshake phase can be cooked into anything. How could WebSocket protocol use such `Origin` values to decide whether or not to accept handshakes from non-browser clients?

And even with a `browser client`, can't user just use JavaScript to create a fake `Origin` header for handshake?

It seems the `Origin` header alone is too fragile.

Answer (score 0):

The Origin header only prevent smartguy.com users from using your websocket service inadvertently, since WebSockets are not affected by the SOP.

Imagine you create a nice trading application that communicates through WebSockets, and now I create a fancy UX application somewhere else, and write javascrit that connects to your service and interacts with it. How does your service know that the user is connecting from the intended page? The Origin header.

Of course, anything can be tampered in a HTTP Request, but that is common to all HTTP communications. You cannot tell if a user is using a C++ client or a browser client.